# Implementation differences between feedforward and backward comb filters

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing

Following https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_filter , I implemented the following feedforward comb filter in Python.

```
def combfilter(x, delay=2, gain=-3):
    memory = []
    y = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        sample = x[i]
        memory.append(sample * db_to_linear(gain))
        if len(memory) > delay:
            y[i] = x[i] + memory.pop(0)
        else:
            y[i] = x[i]
    return y
```

At the end of the Wikipedia article, the feedback formulation is given: `y(t) = x(t) + alpha * y(t - tau)`.

I tried to implement the feedback comb filter, but it seems to me that the implementation would be the same as the feedforward one. Is it normal?

What does the feedback formulation changes to the Python implementation? How can I implement the feedback version?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the value of alpha?

Comment: alpha is the gain of the feedback loop, so let's say -3dB. In my feedforward implementation, I call the variable `gain` the gain applied to the delayed signal.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of feedback comb filter must be different. You keep `y` in memory instead of `x`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# impulse signal to make it easier to analyse
input_signal = np.zeros(50)
input_signal[10] = 1


def combfilter(x, delay=2, gain=-3):
    memory = []
    y = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        sample = x[i]
        memory.append(sample * 10 ** (gain / 10))
        if len(memory) > delay:
            y[i] = x[i] + memory.pop(0)
        else:
            y[i] = x[i]
    return y


def feedback_combfilter(x, delay=2, gain=-3):
    memory = []
    y = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if len(memory) > delay:
            y[i] = x[i] + memory.pop(0) * 10 ** (gain / 10)
        else:
            y[i] = x[i]
        memory.append(y[i])
    return y

plt.plot(input_signal, 'k')
plt.plot(combfilter(input_signal), '--')
plt.plot(feedback_combfilter(input_signal), ':')
plt.legend(['original signal', 'comb filter', 'feedback comb filter'])
plt.show()
```

[image]